# php $_GET variables rewirte to subdomain htaccess 1

Tags: .htaccess

I Got this URL

```
http://localhost/test/test.php/1
```

This is I want to

```
http://localhost/test/test.php?a=1
```

**test.php**

```
echo $_GET['a'];
```

**How to write .htaccess rule for it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/test\.php/(\d+)$ /test/test.php?a=$1 [L]
```

Put this in htaccess file and place it in the document root directory of apache.